# How to create foreign key linked fields in forms just like in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In django admin, you can add, edit, and even delete objects from another model if there is a relationship between the two.

For instance, if my code looks like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

When I am editing/adding a product using the django admin site, in the category field, I have 3 buttons to add/edit/delete categories. Adding one takes to a new window, and once I submit the form, the category is added, the window is closed, and I am returned to my product form with the extra category present. Like this:

[image]

How can I do this in my normal application (outside the admin) using forms?

Comment: What is your normal application?

Comment: @SachinKukreja Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do what django admin does, which is to link the `add` button to this:

```
/admin/<your_app>/<your_model>/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1
```

and then it uses a bit of javascript to get back the new object you just created. If you look into the `contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js` file (in django's code), you'll see a few functions that pass the id of the calling field to the popup (in `showRelatedObjectPopup`), and then bring back the selected id (in `dismissRelatedLookupPopup`).

This is for adding a new object, but you can look into the logic for changing/deleting.

You can replicate that logic with your own forms.